# Java maven project building with clean, install, run as

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Many times I find that for my changes to take effect while working on a Maven/java project I need to Maven clean -> Maven install -> run as ..

[image: Screenshot here]

How can I automate this in Eclipse?
So every time Im running the application it would clean, install then run

Comment: You can use `Maven update` (alt+F5). Also in you Preference->Maven there is an "Automatically update Maven configuration" option, you might want to select that.

Answer (score 2):

If you select option 5 "Maven build...", you will get a window where you can specify different goals. Put in `clean install` and click Run. This will create a new menu item (which you can also name) in the "Run As..." menu.

Answer (score 1):

Install the m2Eclipse plugin in your eclipse
http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

or create bat file in your project with command `mvn clean install`